# Счёт чисел

Tags: html, javascript

Есть три текстовых поля и одна кнопка.

```
<INPUT type="text" name="1" value="10">
<INPUT type="text" name="2" value="20">
<INPUT type="text" name="answer" value="">
<INPUT type="button" name="button" onclick="">
```

У двух из них присвоены значения 10 и 20. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 'button' складывались значения текстовых полей 1 и 2, и чтобы результат был в третьем текстовом поле 'answer'? Т.е. в данном случае, после нажатия на кнопку, в текстовом поле 'answer' должно быть число 30. Мне желательно, чтобы это было на Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/41593nc3/

Учебное задание же!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var btn=document.getElementsByName('button')[0];
    btn.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementsByName('answer')[0].value = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('1')[0].value) + parseInt(document.getElementsByName('2')[0].value);
    }
});
```

Comment: А делить можно?

Comment: Можно. Но для деления проверяйте на ноль.